stm32f4discovery Board not Recognized by STM32CubeProgrammer nor CubeMX on PC
I have an STM3F4DISC1 board that seems like it does connect to my Windows 10 PC (shows up in the system tray as an ejectible USB device). The device gets powered on and starts running the factory configured firmware as shown below

However I cannot connect it to CubeMX or Cube Programmer. I get the 'ST-LINK error (DEV_CONNECT_ERR)' error. I've tried to install the driver manually too, but to no avail.
When I try doing a 'core reset' via Cube32 programmer, I see the following

Perhaps the onboard firmware is preventing it from being accessed? What could it be? Do I need to have the board in some "developer mode" setting? I haven't played with the jumpers on the board and they are as is.
What is it that I'm doing wrong? Keen to hear from you folks

You can copy bin file to that drive to upload it. There is also ST-link upgrade binary somewhere on ST site, maybe it's old firmware.

@KIIV upload which bin file & where? I don't think the board is mounted anywhere as a drive but can it be? I don't follow what you're saying

@KIIV means you can copy the image to the USB drive that is registered when you connect the board.  However that does not support debug, so while true, does not really solve your problem.

From the photo it is not clear how you have have the ST-Link/Discovery jumpers set.  Both jumpers in CN3 should be fitted.  Target power showing 0V is not correct though.

I'd start with that button called "Firmware upgrade" near Target voltage. Just check if your firmware is latest. The target voltage is taken from stlink_3v3 (it's not even routed to the swd header), jumpers seems to be in place.
